# R: "Which" function gives unexpected (and unwanted) results when using a comparison (>=)

Tags: r, comparison

I do not understand why the "which" function is not giving the right result here. I just want to select airports in Pennsylvania with more than 5,000 commercial service operations, and the result always contains a number of commercial service operations inferior to 5,000, as seen below.

I have read several questions indicating issues with "which", but I have seen none of that sort, and I have not had this issue before using this function.

```
Test4<-Airports[which(Airports$LAN_FA_TY=="AIRPORT" & 
                      Airports$STATE_NAME=="PENNSYLVANIA" & 
                      Airports$COMM_SERV>= "5000")
                , ]
Test4$COMM_SERV
# [1] 77680    73    71
```

Comment: In future, use the `{}` button to enclose code in code blocks, not the `"` button.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `str(Airports)` (include it in your question).

Comment: Or just type `sapply(Airports,class)`

Answer (score 3):

In this code snippet `Airports$COMM_SERV>= "5000"` you're using " " around a numeric value (the 5000) which turns the number into a character  <strike>and hence you can no longer use mathematical operations like `>=` with that character</strike>. Just remove the "" and it should work as expected.  (The use of comparison operators for character objects is allowed and meaningful. See `?'>='`. It's just that the results may not be what were expected.)

Looking at your code, you could also profit from using `with()` to reduce the typing and improve readability:

```
with(Airports, Airports[which(LAN_FA_TY == "AIRPORT" & STATE_NAME == "PENNSYLVANIA" & COMM_SERV >= 5000),])
```

Comment: Nice answer, which leads me to think you should change your name to "endR"  -- except that Mr. Wiggins might come after you :-)

Comment: Very interesting, @jlhoward - thanks for the insight here. We might need to see the `str(Airports)` output then.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thanks (although it seems the answer may be wrong). Unfortunately, I don't quite understand who is Mr. Wiggins..

Comment: @beginneR He's referencing a character from a popular sci-fi novel called Ender's Game.

Comment: `subset()` might be even better than `with()`: `subset(Airports, LAN_FA_TY == "AIRPORT" & STATE_NAME == "PENNSYLVANIA" & COMM_SERV >= 5000)`

Comment: @jlhoward: The mere fact that the "5000" is quoted would make this a character-oriented lexical comparison. The answer as it stands is also  wrong because you can use comparison operators with characters.

Comment: @BondedDust, thanks for correcting my answer! Seems I answered a little too hastily.

Comment: Thank you very much everybody and sorry I didn't thank you earlier. Where could i find good info on the difference between "which" and "subset"? Are there situations where I shouldn't use "which"?